# Big O notation, prove that 3N^2 + 3N - 30 = O(N^2) is true

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I want to reason this out with basic arithmetic:

Problem:

`3N^2 + 3N - 30  = O(N^2)`  prove that this is true.

What I have so far:

```
T(N) = 3N^2 + 3N - 30
```

I have to find c and n0 in which t(N) <= c (N^2) for all N >= n0 to prove the statement is true. I replace 3N^2 + 3N - 30  with 3N^2 + 3N^2 - 30N^2 since this is >= 3N^2 + 3N - 30 .

3N^2 + 3N^2 - 30N^2 is -24N^2 for all N>=1 . Thus c = -24 and n0 = 1 to prove the statement is indeed = O(N^2)

Is this correct? If not, what should I do to make this correct?

Problem: Prove that 3N^2 +3N - 20 = omega (N^2)

What I have so far:

Still trying to find c and n0 first. 3N^2 +3N -20 >= N^2 and thus c is 1 and n0 is 1 to prove this statement is indeed equal to omega (N^2)

Comment: With regard to problem (1), any analysis that yields a negative constant `c` is certainly wrong.  In this case, although `30N^2` is not less than 30 for any non-negative `N`, it is not correct to substitute one for the other because you are subtracting, not adding.  Better to substitute `- 0` for `- 30`.

Comment: So I should have for (1): 3N^2 + 3N^2 +0 >= 3N^2 + 3N^2 -30 and have 6 = c and 0 be n0?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not understanding this correctly, but would what I wrote for problem 2 work then? also for my post to problem 1 above your post, that would be correct?

Comment: I'm not sure whether problem (2) is supposed to refer to the same equation as problem (1).  It doesn't, but it is subject to the same upper-bound analysis.  As for the lower bound, you need to find a positive constant `c'`, necessarily smaller than the one from the upper bound analysis, and determine what `n1'` works with it to yield `c' * N^2 <= f(N)` for all `N` larger than `n1'`.  In this case, choosing `c'` as 1 makes for a pretty simple analysis.

Comment: What you already have for problem (2) is not correct.  `3 * (1^2) + 3 * 1 - 20` is less than `1^2`, so the designated `c` and `n0` fail to satisfy the lower-bound criterion even at `n0`.

Comment: With respect to problem (1), yes, your revised analysis yielding `c` = 6, `n0` = 0 is correct.  Remember, though, that there are many combinations that work -- that pair is just one example.

Comment: ah gotcha. Thank you ^^

Comment: @John Bollinger Why not make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: Nice gerenalization just to get into it: Prove that `an^2 + bn + c = O(n^2)` for any integers `a`, `b`, `c`.

Comment: @ John please do. Also for problem number 2, you said I should choose c = 1 for simple analysis, so would N^2 - 20 work for all N>= 0?

Comment: Another nice and important generalization: for every polynomial `p` we have `p=O(n^k)`, where `k` is the degree of `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For problem 2, let `n_0:=10` and `c:=2`. Let `n>=n_0`. By the chain of inequalities

```
3n^2 + 3n - 20 >= 3n^2 - 20
               >= 3n^2 - 100
               >= 3n^2 - n^2
                = 2n^2
                = cn^2
```

we obtain the desired result.

Comment: In fact, it's all contained in the comments above.